# Multipart issues with chunking

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am trying to setup a test implementation of FineUploader, but I am running into a problem with chunking.  I have debug set to true, and everything seems to be going great until the very end of the process where I get the following errors:

> "[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] All chunks have been uploaded for 0 - finalizing...." custom.fineuploader-5.0.2.js:207
>   "[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting All Chunks Done request for 0" custom.fineuploader-5.0.2.js:207
>   "[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending POST request for 0" custom.fineuploader-5.0.2.js:207
>   "[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Received response status 200 with body: {"error":"Server error. Not a multipart request. Please set forceMultipart to default value (true).","uploadName":null,"template":"undefined","category":"undefined"}" custom.fineuploader-5.0.2.js:207
>   "[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Finalize successful for 0"

The bottom error says "Server error. Not a multipart request. Please set forceMultipart to default value (true).", but as far as I can tell my code it setup that way already.  Here is what I have in the code for it:

```
var uploadHandler = $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
            debug: true,
            request: {
                endpoint: 'server/endpoint.php',
                forceMultipart: true,
                params: // send the values to backend file (endpoint.php)
                {
                    template:function() {
                        return $("#price_template_id").val();
                    },
                    category:function(){
                        return $("#category_id").val();
                    }
                }
            },
            validation: { // validation for the images uploaded
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg'],
                sizeLimit: 20971520 // 20 MB = 20 * 1024 * 1024 bytes 20971520
            },
            editFilename: {
                enabled: true
            },
            display: { //display image on upload
                fileSizeOnSubmit: true
            },
            resume: { //enable resume on upload
                enabled: true
            },
            retry: {  //enable retry on upload
                enableAuto: true
            },
            forceMultipart: {
                enabled: true
            },
            chunking: { //enable chunking on upload
                concurrent: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enabled: true,
                partSize: 200000, //200KB per chunk
                success: {
                    endpoint: 'server/endpoint.php'
                }
            },
            template: "qq-template",
            autoUpload: true, 
            showMessage: function(message) {  //show message if any error occur during uplaod process
                alert(message); 
            }
        })
```

You can see/test the implementation here: http://web3.instaproofs.com/temp/fineuploaderv3/

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is not properly handling the "all chunks done" POST request.  This is not a multipart encoded request.  It is sent by Fine Uploader after the last chunk has successfully been uploaded to the server.  This POST contains a URL-encoded message-body with information about the completed chunked file.  Your server should combine all chunks associated with the file and then respond appropriately.  More info at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/concurrent-chunking.html#server-side-implications.

Comment: Thanks!  I am using the endpoint and handler from the github repository, here: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php/traditional  I believe that this handles putting the pieces back together, but it sounds like maybe something is missing.  Are there any *complete* examples out there for FineUploader, which show how everything comes together?  It seems that most people have issues with this uploader because there really isn't a complete example to draw off of (that is easily found).

Comment: This is a very complex uploader with a large number of supported workflows.  Are there server-side examples that cover every possible server-side language and workflow?  No.  Unfortunately, that's not realistic given the amount of time that would take to create.  There are, however, examples for the most common workflows in many languages in the [fine-uploader-server GitHub repo](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server).  For the less common-workflows, there is extensive documentation on the docs site that explains how you can handle requests in your server-side language of choice...

Comment: ...You are using concurrent chunking, which is not a common feature (and very new).  It is meant to be used to improve the efficiency of very large single file uploads.  Just follow the documentation I pointed you to to handle the additional POST request sent by Fine Uploader when using this workflow, and you should be fine.  All you need to do is take one of the common server-side examples in the examples repo, and augment it to handle the "all chunks done" POST request.  If you run into issues, be sure to post a question with your server code.

Comment: Alright, I think I am on the right track now.  The PHP example in github doesn't support concurrent chunking or the new chunking success POST, so I will need to extend it and add that ability on my server.  Thanks for the help and the point in the right direction!

Comment: I got it all working now.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working!  No additional code in the examples should be required to support concurrent chunking.  You only need to add support for the "all chunks done" request by registering this request handler and moving the logic that combines the chunks into this handler.

Comment: Although I got the job done without it, my opinion is still that it would be very beneficial for everyone if the functionality was included in the sample code.  The sample PHP code hasn't been updated in 6 months, and a little update now and again would be awesome.  

Thanks again for the help.